# How to configure the server to send appropriate MIME type for JavaScript?

Tags: php, jsonp

I have a JSON file on PHP server.

I am using AJAX to call the JSON file, and I receive this error:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain:
```

File on the server PHP has extensions

```
resources.json
```

content

```
callback=({
    "urlFile": "http://mysite.com/xxx/xxx/xxx/test.zip"
});
```

I would like to know the simplest way to make sure JSON is return to the client as `application/json`

I am using APACHE

Comment: You can put an extension and set mimetype in htaccess or you can send php header as application/json: `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: could you provide a sample for the htaccess?

Comment: Something like **AddType application/json .json**. It's not tested!

Comment: What server software are you using? Apache? IIS? nginx?